# trigger MySql con varios elementos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, trigger

estoy trabajando en un proyecto de mensajeria, al mensajero se le asigna un servicio que va en la tabla service, este asocia unos productos ligados al id_service en una tabla llamada service_product y alli se guarda la cantidad de unidades que solicito el usuario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la tabla product_stock guarda el stock de cada producto asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando el mensajero indica en android que el servicio fue exitoso se le cambia el estado del servicio a 9
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi caso de uso me pidieron hacer un trigger que cuando el estado del servicio sea 9 reste la cantidad de unidades de la tabla service_product a la columna stock_current de mi tabla product_stock.

esto lo logre haciendo este trigger pero solo me funciona cuando el servicio lleva un solo producto, ya que si lleva mas de 1 los select retornan mas de 1 fila

```js
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `deliver_db_v2`.`service_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `service` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if NEW.service_state_id = 9
then
UPDATE product_stock 
SET stock_current=stock_current-(SELECT quantity from service_product where service_id=OLD.id)
where  product_id=(SELECT product_id from service_product where service_id=OLD.id);
end if;
END
```

Gracias a quien me pueda ayudar

Comment: Deberías agregar el trigger completo

Comment: ya lo complemente,gracias por revisar

Comment: Podrías poner las tablas sin imágenes?

Comment: Sí, agrega la estructura de las tablas así podemos crear la base de datos

Comment: te paso los script de las tablas?

Comment: si, exactamente

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que filtrar también por product, sino traes todos los registros para ese producto. Si el service tiene mas de un producto te trae la quantity de todos los productos, por eso te dice que tiene multiples filas. El update quedaría mas o menos así:

```
UPDATE product_stock p INNER JOIN service_product s ON p.product_id=s.product_id
SET p.stock_current=p.stock_current-s.quantity
WHERE s.service_id=OLD.id
```

Probalo antes porque yo no lo hice.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, los registros se actualizaron perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hay que sustituir es el UPDATE dentro del TRIGGER.  Una opción es usar tablas temporales, sustituye el UPDATE por estas sentencias:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Qty SELECT product_id, quantity FROM service_product WHERE service_id=OLD.id;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Products SELECT product_id FROM service_product WHERE service_id=OLD.id;
UPDATE product_stock SET stock_current = stock_current - (SELECT quantity FROM Qty WHERE Qty.product_id=product_stock.product_id) WHERE product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM Products);
```

Utilizo 2 tablas temporales ya que una tabla temporal solo se puede referenciar una vez en el query, entonces no se podía reutilizar la primera tabla temporal para el WHERE del UPDATE.

Comment: hola, gracias por revisar. Cuando hago ese cambio y se ejecuta el trigger me trae este error   <-----When @@GLOBAL.ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY = 1, the statements CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can be executed in a non-transactional context only, and require that AUTOCOMMIT = 1. These statements are also not allowed in a function or trigger because functions and triggers are also considered to be multi-statement transactions.
SQL Statement:--->

Comment: Nicolas, por lo que leo acá esa restricción de uso de tablas temporales en triggers aplica al usar GTID (es decir la variable enforce_gtid_consistency está encendida) según este enlace: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-gtids-restrictions.html. Tenés posibilidad de apagarlo y probarlo?

Comment: no, el servidor de la bd es ajeno al equipo de desarrollo y ellos no habilitan esas opciones, igual probe tu query en ambiente local y me retorna un 1242 porque el primer subquery trae varios registros, no sabe cual se debe insertar

Comment: Yo lo probé en este fiddle con algunos datos inventados y me funciona el UPDATE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afe707/1